How to create a UITextField with inline validation error?
Im trying to build a custom UITextField that shows a validation error inline below the textfield akin to material design. Im adding a UILabel lazily and constraining to the textfield when i present the error
    private lazy var errorLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
        label.textColor = errorColor
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.isHidden = true
        return label
    }()

    open override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        
        // Make sure that errorLabel is added once to the superview, not to the text field itself
        if let superview = superview, errorLabel.superview == nil {
            superview.addSubview(errorLabel)
            configureErrorLabelConstraints()
        }
    }

    private func configureErrorLabelConstraints() {
        errorLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            errorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
            errorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            errorLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor)
        ])

    public func showInlineValidationError(message: String) {
        errorLabel.textColor = errorColor
        layer.borderColor = errorColor.cgColor
        errorLabel.text = message
        errorLabel.isHidden = false
    }
    
    public func hideInlineValidationError() {
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        errorLabel.isHidden = true
    }
    }

This all works great. My issue is, say i have a UIImage constrained 12 points below the custom textfield, when the label is presented it does not move the image down by the label height, and rather reduces the space between the two. What i want is if the label is displayed, the constraint between the textfield and image to be increased by how much additional height the label takes up. How can i go about this? AI has not been helpful at all in what i might be able to do here.
Im open to a 3rd party library if its basic enough. I just need a basic UITextfield with rounded corners and the error label below that can support my height change requirements

This is similar to what sonle suggested.  I ended up moving this to a UIView containing a stackview and hide/show the label.  if i have a height constraint it must be set to greater than or equal to so the view is allow to grow with the stackview.
open class ErrorTextField: UIView {
    public var errorColor: UIColor = .red
    public var errorLabelTopSpacing: CGFloat = 5
    public var textfieldHeight = 48
    public var textfieldBorderWidth: CGFloat = 1
    public var textfieldCornerRadius: CGFloat = 4
    public var errorLabelFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
    
    public let textField = UITextField()
    
    public var errorLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.isHidden = true
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [textField, errorLabel])
        return stack
    }()
    
    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupViews()
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = textfieldCornerRadius
        textField.layer.borderWidth = textfieldBorderWidth
        errorLabel.font = errorLabelFont
        errorLabel.textColor = errorColor
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = errorLabelTopSpacing
        
        addSubview(stackView)
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(textfieldHeight)),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    public func showError(message: String) {
        errorLabel.text = message
        textField.borderColor = errorColor
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: .zero, options: .curveEaseOut) {
        self.errorLabel.isHidden = false
        self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    }
    
    public func hideError() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.errorLabel.isHidden = true
            self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}



Update: According to your comment I assume this is what you're looking for.

Declare a base class, let's call ValidationTextField, that contains three subviews like below.
Next, subclass it for a specific purpose, I will do a example about EmailTextField.

class ValidationTextField: UIView {
    struct Config {
        let keyboardType: UIKeyboardType
        let error: String
        //Other configures if needed
    }
    
    private var textField = UITextField()
    private var errorLabel = UILabel()
    private var errorImage = UIImageView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //Add subViews within stackView here
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    func bind(_ config: ValidationTextField.Config) {
        textField.keyboardType = config.keyboardType
        errorLabel.text = config.error
    }

    func validate(_ text: String?) -> Bool {
        //TODO: should be overridden
        return true
    }

    private func toggleError(isShow: Bool) {
        guard (!errorLabel.isHidden && !isShow) || (errorLabel.isHidden && isShow) else { return }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.errorLabel.isHidden = !isShow
        }
    }

    @objc private func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let isValid = validate(textField.text)

        toggleError(isShow: !isValid)
    }
}

And this is what EmailTextField could look like:
final class EmailTextField: ValidationTextField {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        bind(.init(keyboardType: .emailAddress, 
                   error: "Email is not valid"))
    }

    override func validate(_ text: String?) -> Bool {
        if let text {
            return validateEmail(text)
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    private func validateEmail(_ text: String) -> Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailTest.evaluate(with: text)
    }


I think the better approach for this scenario is to add a container StackView that contains all textField, errorLabel and imageView vertically.

Then you can simply toggle the errorLabel regardless of Label's height and the constraints between TextField and ImageView.
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.errorLabel.isHidden.toggle()
}

Output:


This is the simple solution, but its not reusable so id have to build logic like this on every textfield.  Is there a way to do this that doesnt require me to do it 10 times over if i have say 10 different textfields with different validation?  Extreme example, i know, but even more than one can turn into a pain rewriting logic over and over.

I've updated the answer, you might want to take a look. However, I suggest splitting the question into two, separately. Hope it will help.
